# Connect to GIT repo through another server

Tags: ssh, bash, git, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

**Current scenario:**

Right now, in order to be able to work with our git repository we do have to use a VPN since the repo server does not have a public IP.

**Goal:**

What I'm trying to accomplish is to set-up a server which does have a public IP and allow git connections to through it to the repo server (private IP).

This could be easily accomplished by using ProxyCommand at the user's local configurations, but in order to make user's life easier I'm looking for something which does not need any special configuration from user side.

Can someone please assist? Thank you.

Comment: you can simply forward some port on the public server to the private one using firewalld or iptables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jakuje. Actually not a valid solution since other users are also login via SSH and this should be set-up only for user "git".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I really think you should go with the ProxyCommand approach. In the long run it will make everyone's life easier.

That being said, what you *could* do, is setup the git user on the external node to relay the git command to the internal node. First of all, that would involve putting something like this in */etc/ssh/sshd_config* on the external node.

```
Match User git
    ForceCommand /usr/local/bin/git_wrapper
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTTY no
```

With the *git_wrapper* script looking something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
    git*)
    ssh -o BatchMode=yes git@internal.host "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Git only"
    ;;
esac
```

You need to make sure that *external.host:~git/.ssh/known_hosts* contains the host key for the internal host.

Then there is the part about the the external.host being able to login as *git@internal.host*. That can either be arranged by having your users enable Agent Forwarding or by giving *git@external.host* an ssh key in *git@internal.host:~/.ssh/authorized_keys*. Neither of these options being without security implications.

**Warning:** Note that the restrictions on the `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` is mostly about preventing your users from doing more than they should by accident. If you don't trust your users not to run arbitrary command either on the external.host nor on the internal.host, don't take this approach.

By the way, did I say that I think you should really take the ProxyCommand approach? Either that, or by setting up some kind forwarding on a networking level.